# Cancan authorisation for a specific model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

Here is what I want to do:

A `User` assigned an `admin` role *cannot* update the role of a `User` with the `god` role. So here's the code I came up with:

```
  if user.has_role? 'admin'
    can :manage, :all
    cannot :update, User do |resource|
      resource.has_role?('god')
    end
  end
```

However, `resource` seems to always return `nil`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to explicitly find the 'User' that's getting updated?

Comment: Ah. I thought that would be `resource`. How should the code look like then?

Comment: I don't use cancan but it doesn't look that way. Not sure, let me dig some notes out

Comment: No, I think I'm wrong. The syntax looks right. You say the resource is nil? Is that the full error you get?

Comment: Do you load the resource using `load_resource` (or `load_and_authorize_resource`) ?

Comment: @simonmorley I used the debugger to trace, and it was reporting `nil`. No errors though. @Olivier Nope, I didn't do that. That should go in the controller I assume?

Comment: I think @oliver is correct you'll need to add something to your controller. And, his point about r4 is poignant. That's why we no longer use it, we ended up rolling our own to avoid such things. Actually there's a railscasts episode that's quite a good start.

Comment: @simonmorley the eternal rails & gems problem :) I still like to use third party gems (provided they give me *exactly* what I want) because when they break, that's a good opportunity to read code from people that took large amount of time on a specific problem. That requires having time to do that, of course, but I would encourage my developers to do it as it's some kind of permanent education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Expected behavior

In order to be able to use the block syntax for `#can` and `#cannot`, you have to first load the resource in your controller. [As doc says](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#only-for-object-attributes) :

> The block is *only* evaluated when an actual instance object is
>   present. It is not evaluated when checking permissions on the class
>   (such as in the index action). This means any conditions which are not
>   dependent on the object attributes should be moved outside of the
>   block.

For this instance object to be present, you need to let cancan load it:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

This will make `@user` available both in your controller and in your block passed to `#cannot`. Now there's a catch.

### ... which breaks on rails-4 (as of 10/2/2013)

CanCan has a problem with rails-4 : it does not handle StrongParameters. This causes automatic resource loading to crash on `#create` and `#update` actions. This is [a running issue](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/pull/768) and Ryan promised a solution for cancan-2 (seems to be abandonned for cancan-1).

Anyway, you can use the code in this PR to make cancan compatible with strong parameters. Here it is extracted in [a monkey patch](https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/ab1a51ed60bde245a8b2). I prefer to use monkey patches rather than pointing gem to specific commit or fork so that I don't lose any master gem update.

### Alternate resource loading

Reading again the doc, I've found an other way to avoid strong parameter problem. You can [overload loader if you use a before_filter before #load_resource](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#override-loading).

There are several implications :

- you have to implement logic yourself to make a difference between `#new`, `#show`, `#create`, etc (may use several conditional filters)
- you have to assigns params yourself (and thus, you can make a proper use of strong parameters)

This defeats the simplicity of cancan resource loading, and serves the sole purpose of letting cancan know what the resource is when you want to use a block with `#can` and `#cannot`.

I would still rather go with the monkey patch, so that you don't end up with a lot of useless code in your controllers when issue is fixed upstream.